# Whats the correct syntax for on conflict do update sqlyte?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to insert clients on a table(importing them from a csv), the email column needs to be unique(in the csv the a client can appear more than one time, the last instance has the correct info) and the ids are created with an autoincrementing value (this is why i cant use select or replace), im trying to use the syntax found in the sqlite guide(and in every question about ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE found here) but sqlite throws a

> SQL logic error near "ON" :syntax error

the query goes like this(using VB)

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO clients(name1,name2,address1,address2,plz,city,country,phoneNumber1,phoneNumber2,cellPhoneNumber,fax,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON CONFLICT(email) DO UPDATE SET name1=excluded.name1,name2=excluded.name2,address1=excluded.address1,address2=excluded.address2,plz=excluded.plz,city=excluded.city,country=excluded.country,phoneNumber1=excluded.phoneNumber1,phoneNumber2=excluded.phoneNumber2,cellPhoneNumber=excluded.cellPhoneNumber,fax=excluded.fax,email=excluded.email;
```

Comment: Are you using sqlite 3.24 or newer?

Comment: Im using a NuGet Package, System.Data.Sqlite(is supported by the same dev team as far as i understand, in its latest version (1.0.109.2) wich is the equivalent of the version SQLite 3.24.0.